# Establish Master child relation with Unbound subform in MS access form

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am working with split database ( MS access) . In front end I do not want to have even links to the tables to avoid anyone editing the tables directly. Also do not prefer the workaround with hiding the navigation pane and operate with pop up . On loading the main form I have set up the connection to backend through VBA and it works fine. The subform connection to a table in backend is also set up through VBA . What is missing is the master - child relation.
 If I use local table or even linked table as source for subform, master-child works fine. How to achieve master-child relation without any table /linked table in front end

Comment: If you wish to go this route, Access is not the tool.

Comment: In VBA, treat the problem like you are coordinating two separate forms. You'll need the parent to set a global variable, accessible through a TempVar or global function. The parent would then send commands to the child to requery,  search, etc. Queries in the child form then sync to the global variable. This is a fairly common 'unbound' setup.